# What happened to the sign of the signed value when shifted to the left?

Tags: unsigned, signed

I have read in the book, The Art of Assembly Language, that the highest order bit in a signed integer represents the sign bit or the sign of the integer. What happened to the sign bit if you shift the binary for of integer to the left?
For example, consider bit 10101010, (signed), if you shift left it, it will become 01010100, the sign will change after.

Comment: It seems you have answered yourself, so what are you still asking?

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I thought changing the sign of a signed integer in left shift process is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"?

Comment: i mean it's not supposed to happen because i read that when you shift left, you just basically multiply it to its radix^n, in binary, 2^n, and in book, he used the example in decimal, 123, when shifted left, will become 123x10^1, 1230. it doesnt say there that it will change sign. i got confused.

Comment: Ok yes, but it's clearly not always possible to keep the sign the same. This does indicate overflow (but for a shift by more than 1 place, overflow can occur even if the sign does not change)

Comment: i understand now. Thank you